# weird function valChange trying to figure out what and why

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so I have this project I recently came on to, so Im still figuring things out and all else. But today I need to add some new stuff, and in doing so I came upon a road block that seems to be brought on by this custom little function someone extended jQuery with

```
$.fn.extend({ valChange: function(v) { return this.val(v).change(); } });
```

the handful of places its used is like

```
$("input#system_path", $form).valChange(data.system_path ? data.system_path : '');
```

now what ever this does in laymens terms is confusing me. However with what I am doing it appears that the elements I need to find the value of on document ready don't seem to have a value, despite actually having a value physically on the page, elements I am trying to find the value on similarly that don't get there values through this means work fine. So I am overall trying to wrap my mind around what the person that made this was thinking, and then if its something I can change to something else great so long as I can get my end game to work the way I want.

I just need someone to look at this and tell me what it is if it makes sense to them, and if it does, is there an alternative I can apply seeing as this is creating a road block?

Comment: Your description of the problems that you're having is not at all clear. What is it that you think this plugin is doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a jQuery plugin that lets you update the value of an element and also trigger a "change" event.

When you update the "value" property of an element, the "change" event normally does not fire. This provides a fairly easy way to do that.

Comment: I appreciate that thank you. Now my problem is why is something in a doc ready thats functionally past this particular event not getting the value. At the bottom of the function that builds the data being output I am adding checks to see if the value is null or undefined which it actually could be. currently testing I try `alert($('#system_path').val());` and get no value from the element even when there was one.

Comment: these checks are intent for triggering something else going on thats being added to the product..

Comment: @chris this function is not for **getting** values, it's for **setting** them.  If you want to get a value, just use `.val()`. If you're not calling this function at all, then it will have no effect at all on the way `.val()` works.